# How to print words that only have more than 10 characters from file?

Tags: java

I've got this question and I'm not very sure how to answer it - I am able to read the file but unsure on how to display only the words with more than 10 characters

Comment: Do you want us to do your homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Tips : `String::length()` is your friend :)

Comment: @MichaelS - Nope not homework, this is optional tests but Ive got unto reading the file and storing the amount of lines in a variable

Comment: how could you know a word is at least 10 char long? Maybe by counting them... Next question, how could you count how many chars a word is made of?

Comment: Just check the length of the words you have stored from the file and print only those which are more than 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although other answers are correct , I recommend using scanner class to read files, as it safely allows to detect end of file conditions and has simpler/more useful utility methods:-

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
while(input.hasNextLine())
{
   String word = input.nextLine();
   if(word.length()>10){
      System.out.println(word)
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, thats the only bit i was stuck on - was getting confused!

Comment: You are checking the length for whole line. However it should check the length of word!

Comment: @hemanth quoting the quetion `Words.txt that contains a sequence of words, one per line` , since there is only one work per line we dont need to check for individual words on each line.

Comment: @RandomMath please mark as answer if proved useful :)

Comment: Yes, you are correct in a way the question being asked!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
private static void readFile(File fin) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fin);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line.length()>10) System.out.println(line);
    }

    br.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suposing you have the word in a `String` variable called word:

```
 if (word.length() > 10)
      System.out.println(word);
```

PS: google before asking!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudo code to help you get started

```
create empty list //where we'll add all the >10char words
read file(split per newline) //see the apache commons api
for each line
    split on space
    for each word in splitted sentence
        if wordLength > 10 add to empty list
print each entry in your filled list
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your logic.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;



    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("your.txt"));    // path for the text file

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

            String line = null;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String st[] = line.split(" ");
                for(int i=0; i<st.length; i++){
                    if(st[i].length()>10) System.out.println(st[i]);
                }

        }
        }

    }
```